# Exclude the terms from determinant

Tags: expression-manipulation

i have a long determinant expression such as

```
delta=8+2a+3b+4c+50a^2+2a^3+70b^2+80a*b+20(a^2)b+5(e^x)+a*b(e^x)+....+3e^(-x)+..
```

I want to exclude the expression like `a^2`, `a^3`, `a*b`, `(a^2)b`... from the determinant to analyze main term. How can I do this?
I try to assign the value of the terms to 0. but for example, I cant assign `a^2=0`.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
delta /. a^n_*b__ /; n > 0 -> 0

(* 8 + 2 a + 3 b + 80 a b + 70 b^2 + 4 c + 3 e^-x + 5 e^x + a b e^x *)
```

If you need to exclude also the terms like `2a` and so on, try this:

```
delta /. a^n_.*b__ /; n > 0 -> 0

(* 8 + 3 b + 70 b^2 + 4 c + 3 e^-x + 5 e^x *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to keep only linear terms of `a, b, c`. This can be done with series expansion:

```
Expand@Normal@Series[delta, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}] /. Thread[Times @@@ Subsets[{a, b, c}, {2}] -> 0]
```

Which gives

```
8 + 2 a + 3 b + 4 c + 3 E^-x + 5 E^x
```

So, first with the `Series` we obtain linear terms of `a, b, c` and also cross-terms like `a b, b c` etc. Then we eliminate such products by replacing rules: `a b -> 0` etc. This can be extended to more variables, you can simply add another `d`. If needed, exponential terms can be eliminated with substitution `E^_ -> 0`.

Comment: Thank you. it solved my problem.

Comment: @cabri61, glad to help you! Thanks for accepting answer and welcome to Mathematica SE!